# API post to more than one table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a API that gets messages saved in a database.

The below controller GETs the message subjects which contain the message chains (two separate tables in my db), I have tested my get requested and works.

I now need to create a POST request, but I'm not sure how to I can send the message subject info and the message chain info in one request, is this possible?

Message Subject contains:

```
        [Key]
    public int MessageSubjectId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message_Chain> Message_Chain { get; set; }
```

Message Chain contains:

```
 [Key]
    public int MessageChainId { get; set; }
    public int MessageSubjectId { get; set; }
    public string MessageBody { get; set; }
    public int SentFromId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public Message_Subject Message_Subject { get; set; }
```

My GET method:

```
   public async Task<ActionResult<IList<Message_Subject>> GetOrderMessagesAsync(int orderNumber)
{
 return await _context.Message_Subject
                   .Where(a => a.orderNumber== orderNumber)
                   .Include(m => m.Message_Chain)
                   .ToListAsync();
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't neeed OrderMessages class. Change your action to this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IList<Message_Subject>> GetOrderMessagesAsync(int orderNumber)
    {
     return await _context.Message_Subject
                       .Where(a => a.orderNumber== orderNumber)
                       .Include(m => m.Message_Chain)
                       .ToListAsync();
      
    }
```